# Completely remove Blade and strip down Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, lumen

How can I completely remove Blade from Lumen and/or what other packages and stuff can I delete to make it as minimalistic as possible. My end goal is to make it very very simple, but keep the critical stuff.

All I need from Lumen is to handle the back end and write an API, so I can use that API for Angular front end - so things like Blade/Auth/Routing etc are not needed, how can I remove them and what else can I remove?

Is there a tutorial for something like this or does someone have any experience regarding this issue?

/edit: I'm aware that it might not affect performance or whatsoever, but I just need to keep everything as simple as possible, it makes me feel better about development if I know that I have stuff, which I actually use.

Comment: If you want super minimal why dont you try out Slim Framework... www.slimframework.com

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do with Lumen in particular? If you really care about paring it all down, I'd be inclined to write my own application from scratch just using reusable components as I see fit (e.g. Aura's router for quick and easy routing, Laravel's Database (for Eloquent), etc.)

Comment: I've done some research and there's many opinions and tests, that all have different outcomes, but arguably Lumen is the fastest micro-framework currently available, which essentially why I want to use it in the first place. I want to keep it as minimal and fast as possible, and I'm also kind-of familiar with the critical parts of Laravel/Lumen, so switching to another framework would also require additional learning and documentation browsing.

Comment: Slim Framework does seem very simple and clean, so I will consider using it, but if there's any way to strip down Lumen into a minimal version like Slime, I will go with that. Thanks for the suggestion @geggleto

Comment: From what I understand is that lumen is the stripped down version of Laravel, you can't really get smaller than lumen.

Comment: That's true, but I guess you could still make it smaller by manually removing things you do not need, which is what I aimed for when creating this post in the first place. However, I'm starting to like Slim Framework and will go with that instead, so thank you once again!

Comment: Just my opinion but apparently benchmarks show Slim is slower than Lumen, so you would be choosing a slower framework, to get less features, that makes no logical sense. If you want to cut Lumen down further you can just fork the repo and amend the composer.json file. Though I wouldn't really recommend it as there will be layers of dependancies that may be hidden. I would go with @alexrussell suggestion, build your own which you can do from Laravel's illuminate repos if thats what you are already used to.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the speed differences probably aren't a huge deal unless you're on shared hosting or the worst VPS ever and have to deal with tens (hundreds?) of thousands of concurrent requests for a sustained period. Obviously, if that sounds like your application then by all means strip your app down, but there is such a thing as premature optimisation :)

Answer (score 2):

To strip down some features of Laravel you can open `config/app.php` and remove service providers and aliases you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with the suggested answer. Don't just go willy nilly removing service providers. It will likely break stuff and composer update would fail.

Even on a fresh build 5.7.x, I tried to remove notificationServiceProvider and laravel couldn't initialize the container and immediately composer update failed. I didn't dig further as I'm sure there are ways to disable it completely but this is just one example.

You have to turn off one dial at a time, run your full regression suite if you have one, composer update, deployment and proceed.